# Compressing source code after build

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, build, msbuild, xcopy

I have to make a compressed zip file of my source code everytime I build the solution.
I've tried to do [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/calvin_hsia/archive/2006/06/06/619191.aspx), so on the project properties page I have this code on the "Post-build event" textbox:

```
if $(ConfigurationName)==Release 
   xcopy /df $(ProjectDir)$(TargetName)*.cs $(ProjectDir)$(TargetName)Source.zip
if $(ConfigurationName)==Release 
   xcopy /df $(TargetDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt) $(ProjectDir)$(TargetName)Runtime.zip
```

but it doesn't work.

It says that

```
Error   1   The command "if ==Release xcopy /df *.csSource.zip
            if ==Release xcopy /df  Runtime.zip
            " exited with code 255. c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets  3717    9   BuildEventHooks
```

How can I make it work?
I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and .NET 4 (MSBuild 4)

Comment: I see it doesn't recognise it. But why? On the macros window I have the ConfigurationName macro.
Also, how can I zip the source code, if xcopy doesn't do that?
Is it any built in command for this?

Comment: Do you actually want to make each build take a **lot** more time? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have to make a zip file from a part of our source code on every build on the build server. This is required, because the source contains plugins which we want to make available to other developers to develop their own plugins.

Comment: I've tried this simplified version too (I previously created the zip file which could be required for xcopy):

xcopy /df $(ProjectDir)$(TargetName)*.cs $(ProjectDir)$(TargetName)Source.zip

But this didn't work neither: "The command "xcopy /df *.cs Source.zip" exited with code 2."

It looks like that a lot of macro don't recognised during the build.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, use a decent source control , like SVN or GIT. Both provides the ability to create "external", that will solve your issue.

Your idea seems very weird, as the build time will greatly increases.

That said, if you want to allow the creation of plugin, isolate your plugin contract (probably an interface) in a custom DLL and ship this DLL. Why would you have to ship source code to create a composable application?

Finally, FYI, **xcopy** won't zip files. You can use 7zip.exe or similar zipping tool, or create a parameterized powershell script that you fire in your post build event. The script can contains the compression you expect.

Here is a sample function that can zip content :

```
function Compress-Directory
{
    [CmdLetBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]
        $SourceDirectory, 
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]
        $Target,
        [ValidateSet("Auto", "Cab", "Zip")] # Supported formats : Cab or Auto for infering the format from the file extension
        [string]
        $Format = "Auto",
        [Switch]$Force
    )
    process{

        if($Format -Match "auto") {
            switch([System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($Target).ToLower())
            {
                ".cab" { $Format = "Cab" }
                ".zip" { $Format = "Zip" }
                default { throw "Could not infer the kind of archive from the target file name. Please specify a file name with a known extention, or use the 'Format' parameter to specify it" }
            }
        }

        if(Test-Path($Target))
        {
            if($Force) { 
                Write-Verbose "Deleting existing archive $Target"
                Remove-Item $Target -Force 
                Write-Verbose "Deleted existing archive $Target"
            }else{
                throw "The target file '$Target' already exists. Either delete it or use the -Force switch"
            }
        }

        switch($Format) {
            "Cab" {
                [void][reflection.assembly]::LoadFile((Join-Path $PSScriptRoot "CabLib.dll"))

                ## the cablib dll can be downloaded from http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com 
                $c = new-object CabLib.Compress 
                $c.CompressFolder($SourceDirectory, $Target, $null, $null, $null, 0) 
                ## thanks to http://www.pseale.com for this function 
            }
            "Zip" {
                Get-ChildItem $SourceDirectory | Compress-ToZip $Target
            }
            default { throw "No compress method known for $Format files."}
        }
    }
}

function Compress-ToZip {
    param([string]$zipfilename)

    Write-Host "Creating the archive $zipfilename"

    if(-not (test-path($zipfilename)))  {
        set-content $zipfilename ("PK" + [char]5 + [char]6 + ("$([char]0)" * 18))
        (Get-ChildItem $zipfilename).IsReadOnly = $false   
    }

    $shellApplication = new-object -com shell.application
    $zipPackage = $shellApplication.NameSpace($zipfilename)

    foreach($file in $input) {
        $zipPackage.CopyHere($file.FullName)    
        $size = $zipPackage.Items().Item($file.Name).Size
        Write-Host "Adding $file" 
        while($zipPackage.Items().Item($file.Name) -Eq $null)
        {
            start-sleep -seconds 1
            write-host "." -nonewline
        }
        write-host " Done" -ForegroundColor Green
    }     

    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($zipPackage) | out-Null
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($shellApplication)| out-Null
}
```

Comment: We use TFS.
I think it could be easy to define a post build script which would run at the build server and not at the local machine.
The sources are not too big, so generating the archive should be fast.
We have to make sample sources available to support our partners.

Comment: I see that you've edited your answer. Thanks for this function! I will look at it, but currently I'm thinking about maybe there is a TFS build target which could zip my files on the Team Foundation Server.

Comment: I think I will repost this question in a more specific format.